# How to get two ingress ports accessible for single service using NGINX kubernetes controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We have one service which has two exposed ports- one is for server and second is for management. Kubernetes cluster have NGINX controller running. Is there any way to expose both the ports of service in Ingress YAML file?
Details:
Service server Port : 8081
Service Management Port: 8082
We tried with two "backends" in Ingress YAML file but it works only for default port which is 80 and fail for any other port. 
ingress.yml file is as below:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: bw-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
   - host: my.host.net
     http:
      paths:
      - path: "/controller/"
        backend:
          serviceName: bw-svc1
          servicePort: 80
       - path: "/actuator/"
         backend:
           serviceName: bw-svc2
           servicePort: 5612
```

Comment: expose those required ports in Dockerfile and configure same port numbers in Service YAML for targetPort

Answer (score 1):

The indentation level of both paths is not equal in your config sample.

Other than that your config looks correct and should result in the following behavior:

1. All traffic coming to the cluster via `my.host.net/controller` will be sent to service `bw-svc1:80`
2. All traffic coming to the cluster via `my.host.net/actuator` will be sent to service `bw-svc2:5612`

If this is not what you'd like to achieve, could you please re-phrase your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The points you mentioned is what I want to achieve. First point is working fine. However for second point I am getting "Connection Refused" error for port 5612. It only works if we provide port 80. Is there any way to achieve this at different ports?

Comment: Check if your service `bw-svc2:5612` is up and running - e.g. load a pod with curl into the cluster and try to `curl https://bw-svc2:5612` from within that particular pod.

Also double-check the readiness and liveness probes are set correctly for `bw-svc2`.

Comment: To start both the services I used NodePort in service YAML file and because of that I got external port to access both the services. With the help of that external port I am able to access the service from out side successfully. That means service is running fine.